# Can't access to one partition of the external hard drive after rename it

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility

My external hard drive has two partitions. I renamed one and after that, I have a problem accessing that partition. When I connect the hard drive to my Macbook, only the partition  (named *HeiHei*) that I didn't rename appears but with a warning
[image].

I went to the Disk Utility and found disk2s2 (the one I renamed) shown as following
[image]

I tried to mount the external hard drive using the command line but failed (*HeiHei* was also not mounted at the beginning and I mounted it using the same method.)

[image]

I highly suspect the problem was because I didn't rename that partition probably (I typed a "." in the new name which might confuse the system?). As you can see below, there is no name assigned to disk2s2 now
[image]

I saved some photos in that partition and there is no backup of them. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!